# Cannot get code to scrape more than one page

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, for-loop, syntax

I want to webscrape multiple pages from a website. I have made code to get one page and I can get it to scrape multiple pages, however I cannot store the information and it only stores data the last page scraped. I need to scrape the contents for which I can then put on data frame. Code is below

```
for page in range(0, 100, 50):
    #This website outputs search results of 50 items per page, for testing I tried to make it 
    get two pages. That it it opens up the links of each page.
    driver.get(f"https://www.website.com/search/{page}...")
       
    firstvariable = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("1stselector")
    secondvariable = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("2ndselector")

    for k in range(len(firstvariable)):
        temporarydata = {"First Variable": firstvariable[k].text,
                         "Second Variable": secondvariable[k].text}
        #check that it does print correctly
        scraperesult.append(temporarydata) #tried adding a (page) index but says not callable
df_data= df_data.append(scraperesult) #Tried df_data= df_data.append(scraperesult)(page) as well
```

Comment: Where is your `scraperesult` defined line?

Comment: Your loop will only run twice, as the range function is only going to return 0 and 50, is that intended behavior? Also, in python you use square brackets [] for indexing.

If your `scraperesult` is defined within the loop, it will be redefined each loop, and will only contain the contents of the last page when appending it to `df_data`.

Comment: Also, the `append` function works in-place, meaning `df_data.append(scraperesult)` is enough, instead of  `df_data=df_data.append(scraperesult)`

Comment: @Xitiz, before this for loop scraperesult was just defined as scraperesult=[ ]

Comment: @rlearner Are you sure about indentation in the given code?

Comment: @Ben, yes that was the intended behavior. Each page of the website has 50 results, and since I am with this range scraping 2 pages, I should have 100 results, but I only get the last 50

Comment: @Ben I had tried your suggestion of adding the [page] index next to scraperesult.append, but now it says it is not subscriptable.

Comment: @Xitiz I think so? The code does run, however it only grabs the elements from the last page

Comment: I am not telling that What I am asking you is if `df_data= df_data.append(scraperesult)` is with a tab then your issue could be happen.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should index it, just pointing out which brackets to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, realizing that my indices were wrong. I had to make the range -50 less so that the first link would be:

```
for page in range(-50, 100, 50):
driver.get(f"https://www.website.com/search/{page}...")
```

the first element being:

```
driver.get(f"https://www.website.com/search/{0}...") #This was what I wanted it to start with
```